# Inserting Tags Into A Database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, for-loop, pdo

I'm attempting at exploding an input that I've named $tags into an array, and then inserting that array into the table `tags`.

I have a class `Global_`with two functions: `post_main()` & `post_tags()`.

In the upload.php file I have them one after the other, such as:

```
$Global_->post_main($_POST['title'], $_POST['subtitle'], $_POST['content'], time(), $_FILES["image-file"]["tmp_name"], $_POST['image-cred'], 
'0', '0', '0', $uid);
$Global_->post_tags($_POST['tags'], $_POST['title']);
```

In the class the `post_tags()` function is as follows:

```
function post_tags($tags, $title) {
        require "database.php";
        $tag_array = explode(", ", $tags);
        $tag_count = count($tag_array);

        $pid_q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `title` = '$title'");
        $pid_q->execute();
        $pid_i = $pid_q->fetch();
        $pid = $pid_i['id'];

        for($i=0;$i < $tag_count;$i++) {
            $t_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `tags` (tag, pid) VALUES (:tag, :pid)");
            $t_stmt->bindParam(':tag', $tag_array[$i]);
            $t_stmt->bindParam(':pid', $pid);
            $t_stmt->execute();
        }
    }
```

The layout for the `tags` table is: `id`, `tag`, and `pid`- which is the ID of the article that it's attached to.

For some reason this data isn't being inserted into the database, although the article's information is. Any idea why?

Comment: try to print  **"INSERT INTO `tags` (tag, pid) VALUES ($tag_array[$i], $pid)** and run on phpmyadmin

Comment: what is this condition: `for($i=0;$i >= $tag_count;$i++) { ` should it be `for($i=0;$i <= $tag_count;$i++) {`

Comment: Does it enter for loop? Why not parameterize `$pid_q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM \`articles\` WHERE \`title\` = '$title'");`? Why not just `foreach($tag_count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your condition for insertion will not be executed because of this(since `$tag_count > 0` as per your question):

```
for($i=0;$i >= $tag_count;$i++) {
```

should it be

```
for($i=0;$i < $tag_count;$i++) {
```

Comment: WOW, what a miss. Just updated it and still no luck - anything else you can think of?

Comment: @JakeMartinez just log or print the insert sql and trying running to phpmyadmin and see what it says whether the sql is constructed properly or not.

Comment: @JakeMartinez i guess you should not update your question based on some answer posted.

Comment: Ah, good call. I thought that I should correct what was wrong, so that if someone new checks it out they wouldn't see a simple error such as that.

In any case, I figured out the issue. At the very bottom of the first function it redirected to the index, skipping over the second entirely. That's the second super simple error I've had; sigh.